# Auto fill letters in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, excel-auto-fill

I want to make a list with the letters A...Z. Is it possible to do that with the auto fill feature through drag&drop or auto fill through the menu? For example if I use A, B, C as a "starting list". I tried various combination of selecting A-C and "dragging" and using the auto fill feature, but nothing worked (I got results like A,B,C,A,B,C...). Something I forgot to get the desired result? (If possible without manually adding an custom list).

From here (for example):

```
Column A
  A
  B
  C
```

and I want to get to this:

```
Column A
  A
  B
  C
  D
  E
  F
  G
  [...]
  Z
```

Please note: I want to have values inside the cells, not formulas.

Comment: Start typing A, B, then C in your column. Then select all three of those values and "grab" the bottom right corner of the selection box (it's a slightly larger square). Just drag the selector down as many rows as you want. There will be a little pop-up indicator of the last value that would be added if you release at that point.

Comment: yeah I tired that already, that only works for numbers (without creating a custom list) thanks for the hint though, I added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the letter manually via a formula:

- In the first cell (for example B2) enter "A"
- In the next cell (i.e. B3) use `=CHAR(CODE(B2) + 1)`
- Drag the cell B3 down until you get Z

To change the formulas to "real" values:

- Select the whole list (A through Z)
- Copy it into the clipboard
- Use "paste content" with values only and "paste" it onto the same position

Comment: I looked around a lot, but I didn't find any better solution, so for now I will mark this as the answer...  but anyone with a "easier" answer (if you think it's easier) please feel free to suggest another solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to type all letters manually on a sheet and follow the below step

1. Go to **File**
2. Click on **Option**
3. Click on **Excel Option**
4. Click on **Advance**
5. Go to **Edit Custom List**
6. Import all Letters that you have already created on a sheet.
7. Click **OK** then again **OK.**
8. Write A and drag the cell using fill handle.

Answer (score 0):

In newer Excel you have an alternative way: `=CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,1,65))`. This formula will generate an array of character values like this

[image: =CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,1,65))]